# I need to obtain graphical display of Mellin transform of any function in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, complex

> $$
> \text{If}\ \ f(x)=\frac{1}{{(1+x)}^k}\ \ ,\ \text{then}
> \ \mathcal{M}\left\{\frac{1}{{(1+x)}^k}\right\}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{t-1}{(1+x)}^{-k}\ \ dx},
> =\frac{\mathrm{\Gamma}(t)\mathrm{\Gamma}(k-t)}{\mathrm{\Gamma}(k)}
> $$
> Its inverse Mellin transform can be found as
> $$
> \mathcal{M}^{-1}{\mathrm{\Gamma}(t)\mathrm{\Gamma}(k-t)}=\frac{\mathrm{\Gamma}(k)}{{(1+x)}^k}$$

Comment: Look up `Plot` or `ReImPlot`/`ComplexPlot` depending on whether you want a real or complex graphical display.

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica has a native `InverseMellinTransform` function. It's unclear what you mean by

> graphical display of Mellin transform of any function

You could mean the plot, in which case something like

```
f[a_, x_] = 
  InverseMellinTransform[(2^(-1 + s) a^-s Gamma[1/2 + s/2])/Gamma[3/2 - s/2], s, x];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[a, x], {a, 1, 4}]], {x, 0, 7}]
```

produces

[image]

Or perhaps you want a graphical display of the expressions for the transforms, in which case

```
flist = {1/s, 1/(s + 1), a^(s - 1), Gamma[s], Gamma[1 - s], Pi Csc[Pi s], 
    Gamma[s]Sin[(Pi s)/2], Cos[(Pi s)/2] Gamma[s], 
 Pi Cot[Pi s], (1/2)Gamma[s/2], 
    (2^(-1 + s) Gamma[1/2 + s/2])/Gamma[3/2 - s/2]}; 
Grid[Join[{{f[s],InverseMellinTransform[f[s],s,x]}},Transpose[{flist,Map[InverseMellinTransform[#,s,x]&,flist]}]],Background->{None,{{None,GrayLevel[.9]}},{{1,1}->Hue[.6,.4,1],{1,2}->Hue[.6,.4,1]}},BaseStyle->{FontFamily->Times,FontSize->12},Dividers->All,FrameStyle->Hue[.6,.4,.8],Spacings->{2,1}]//TraditionalForm
```

produces

[image]

Note that both of these were taken pretty much directly from the documentation. That's a good place to start looking when you want to learn about how to do things in Mathematica.

Comment: thanks , your answer is convincible to me. Can u please guide me more?  To obtain solution of any differential equation through Mellin transform , How we can plot it on Mathematica ?

Comment: @MsNoreen Please be more specific and clearly explain what it is you want. Give an example of what you are trying to do.